# Ternary logic for result (not about ternary operator)

Tags: java, logic, boolean-logic

I have a code (Java for example):

```
    boolean A(...){
       if (...) return true;
       else return false;
    }

    void C(...){

       if (A) {doSomeThing();}
       else {doNothing();}
    }
```

But logic is changed and today i need return 3 cases. It look something like this

```
        int A(...){
           if (...){ return int;}
           else {
              if (...) {return int;}
              else {return int;}
           }
        }

        void C(...){

           if (A == 1) {doSomeThing1();}
           if (A == 2) {doSomeThing2();}
           if (A == 3) {doSomeThing3();}
        }
```

Is this a best practices or I should use something other instead of "int"?  Or I should change my logic and divide it on two boolean?
P.S. I know that this questions are fully but it disturbs me.

Comment: Use [`switch-case`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: Well, a good suggestion would require more information about what those methods do. For example, can it change in future to return more values?

Comment: For example, I have a textbox and handler for it that displays a warning "wrong quantity of symbols". But today i want display 3 types - "too more symbols", "too many" and nothing message.

Comment: using  three  if checks  for the same variable  checking is  definitely a bad practice , why  suppose " A is 1"  in that case "doSomeThing1()"  will happen  but still the code will go ahead and try 2 un needed  IF checks . I  would  recommend   Change to multiple if  to "if else if "  or  switch case.

Answer (score 7):

Best practice would be to use enum type instead of boolean.

```
public enum PossibleValues {
  TRUE, FALSE, NEITHER;
}
```

Comment: And a switch, as per Ruchira's answer :)

Comment: Well, I took this question was about proper type to use.

Answer (score 4):

Actually how many condition you should check is depends on your requirement. For that you can use `if-else` or `swith-cases`.

Comment: And an enum, as per user1455836's answer.

Comment: @CompuChip it is upto you. It will give more readability.

Comment: You can also add additional logic as enum methods. And compiler would say you if you accidentally use non-existent value.